# Tkinter progress bar do something when end and stays on screen

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this simple code which runs a progress bar for 15 seconds.
What i want is when progress bar reach 15 seconds to call a function or print something and the bar to remain fill in on the screen, not to reset and again get into loop

thanks in adavnce

```
import Tkinter
import ttk


def main():

  root = Tkinter.Tk()

  ft = ttk.Frame()

  ft.pack(expand=True, fill=Tkinter.BOTH, side=Tkinter.TOP)

  pb_hd = ttk.Progressbar(ft, orient='horizontal', mode='determinate')

  pb_hd.pack(expand=True, fill=Tkinter.BOTH, side=Tkinter.TOP)

  pb_hd.start(150)

  root.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me say that what's the purpose of that remain to me a bit obscure... Anyway there are a lot of ways to do what you asked about. One could be the following:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import Tkinter
import ttk

def on_loading(widget, value, loading_end):
    print 'loading...'
    widget.start(150)
    sleep(15)
    widget.stop()
    value(100)
    on_ready()

def on_ready():
    print "now ready to work..."

def main():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    ft = ttk.Frame()
    ft.pack(expand=True, fill=Tkinter.BOTH, side=Tkinter.TOP)

    value = 0 #the value of the progressbar
    setvalue = lambda x,value=value: value+x #the lambda to capture value
    pb_hd = ttk.Progressbar(ft, orient='horizontal', mode='determinate', max=100.0, variable=value)
    pb_hd.pack(expand=True, fill=Tkinter.BOTH, side=Tkinter.TOP)

    #Creates a thread that call on_loading
    Thread(target=on_loading, args=(pb_hd, setvalue, on_loading_end)).start()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The purpose is that i count 15 seconds for something to happen and want do it with progress bar. Is there any other option that does not use threads/? is that possible?

Comment: Using threads is mandatory in this case. If you wait before calling mainloop() the program will wait before showing the GUI, but if you wait after calling mainloop() that waiting will happen only when you close the GUI (i.e. by pressing the x button in the window). Anyway if you wait in a different thread that waiting will happen concurrently to the mainloop() execution.